# Role based login with dropdownlist in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, roles

I am making a login form for student and teacher. The code for login form is

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TeacherLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="E_T_Manager.TeacherLogin" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- start: Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap Metro Dashboard">
    <meta name="author" content="Dennis Ji">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Metro, Metro UI, Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <!-- end: Meta -->

    <!-- start: Mobile Specific -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- end: Mobile Specific -->

    <!-- start: CSS -->
    <link id="bootstrap-style" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="base-style" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="base-style-responsive" href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- end: CSS -->


    <!-- The HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <link id="ie-style" href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link id="ie9style" href="css/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- start: Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- end: Favicon -->

            <style type="text/css">
            body { background: url(img/bg-login.jpg) !important; }
        </style>



</head>

<body>
        <div class="container-fluid-full">
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="login-box">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="frm" runat="server">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Username is required." ForeColor="#CC0000">Username is required.*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Pwd" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ForeColor="#CC0000">Password is required.*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </div>
                    <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Username">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon user"></i></span>
                        <asp:TextBox class="input-large span10" ID="UserName" runat="server" placeholder="Type UserName"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Password">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon lock"></i></span>
                               <asp:TextBox class="input-large span10" ID="Pwd" runat="server" placeholder="Type Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Role">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon lock"></i></span>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Roles" runat="server" class="input-large span10">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Select Role</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="button-login">  
                            <asp:Button class="btn btn-primar" ID="T_S_login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="T_S_login_Click" />  
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
                    <hr> 
                    <h3>Forgot Password?</h3>
                    <p>
                        No problem, <a href="ForgotPassword.aspx"> click here</a> to get a new password.
                    </p>    
                </div><!--/span-->
            </div><!--/row-->


    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->

        </div><!--/fluid-row-->

    <!-- start: JavaScript-->

        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>

        <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

        <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

        <script src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/excanvas.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.chosen.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.noty.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.elfinder.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.iphone.toggle.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.gritter.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.knob.modified.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/counter.js"></script>

        <script src="js/retina.js"></script>

        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- end: JavaScript-->

</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind is

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace E_T_Manager
{
    public partial class TeacherLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void T_S_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string connc = @"Data Source=KHAWAR-PC.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ETManager;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connc);

                con.Open();

                string query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName ='"+UserName.Text+"' and Password='"+Pwd.Text+"' and Roles='"+Roles.SelectedValue+"'";

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["New"] = UserName.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("Teacher.aspx");
                }                
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid UserName or Password or Role Type')</script>");

                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have implemented it for the login to teacher so far but I was failed to do so for student area. Can anybody tell me how to make user login either as a teacher or a student with sessions.

Comment: This question is a little bit broad. What is your specific problem with that?

Comment: this code need to be rewritten from scratch due to many problem/issues/security leak (nowadays you cannot write sql injection prone code)